# How to pass space separated filenames list to the rake task?

Tags: ruby, arguments, rake, task, filenames

I need to pass filenames to my rake task as command line arguments and the format is specified, so I can't pass any comma separated array. It must looks like that:

```
file_1.coffee file_2.coffee file_3.coffee
```

How can I pass something like that to the rake task and read it? The list size isn't specified, it's dynamic.

Comment: Passing file names given by functionality of CircleCI. It provides list of filenames in this format, I must take them as argument to my task and I can't preformat it.